# HTTP Request Client Timeout Default Settings

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

I have a server which will take many seconds before it is able to respond to an HTTP Request. I have little influence over the client language / framework used to generate the requests and want to know how long they will wait for a response. I appreciate this will vary for different frameworks / APIs so I want to know the default values for as many as you can identify.

So - what framework / API are you using and what is the default HTTP Request Timeout.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is 100 seconds as per MSDN.